# MySQL: Cannot create table with VARBINARY?

Tags: php, mysql, database, varbinary

I am running this query to set up a `VARBINARY` (I wish for it to be so, for a real reason) field for my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_books` (`id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`book` VARBINARY, `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL, UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`))
```

It hands me a standard syntax error telling me to check all the remaining code after 'VARBINARY'.

My MySQL server version is `5.0.87.d10`, which is claimed to support the datatype since 5.0.

I changed `VARBINARY` directly into `int` and the query worked fine, could there be something I left out after it?

Comment: `for a real reason` Care to elaborate?

Comment: Col. Shrapnel: It's being GZipped, but I really did not want somebody suggesting or asking why I wanted this or that, when I knew what I was doing there. I guess you did what I didn't want anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify a length for [var]binary fields, just as you do for char/varchar.

Comment: Confused myself, I assumed because it was variable length it didn't need a max at the moment, It is late, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add size of varbinary:

```
VARBINARY( 100 )
```